Calling function in electron with React
Running an application both in browser and packaged with electron. Electron is doing some printing stuff in windows files which the browser cannot, however user's can still use the browser version. I need the differentiate in React when browser is used to not prompt for print.
What I have tried:

    const isElectron = () => {
                return (
                    typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
                    typeof window.process === 'object' &&
                    window.process.type === 'renderer'
                ) || (
                    typeof process !== 'undefined' &&
                    typeof process.versions === 'object' &&
                    !!process.versions.electron
                );
            };



This question is similar to: Detect an Electron instance via JavaScript. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
